# Probability of rolling $(6, 2, 2)$ with $3$ dice in which $6$ is twice as likely to occur than any other side

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

Suppose you have $3$ dice, each of which has $6$ occurring with probability twice as much as any other side. What is the probability of rolling $(6,2,2)$?

Trying to get this number to decimal of $3$ places $0$.???

Comment: so you have  *normal* $7$ -faces dice and you are looking for the prob. of getting $(6 or 7, 2,2)$, which is not difficult to answer

Comment: The probabilities are: $2/7,1/7,...1/7. \ \ 2/7+5\cdot 1/7=1$

Comment: @zoli: the second part of your comment is incorrect. You should take a product, not a sum.

Comment: Do you need the specific order 6, 2, 2; or just a 6 and two 2s in any order?

Comment: @paw88789: I meant that the sum of these numbers was one.

Answer (score 1):

Case where $6$ occurs twice as much as any other side is same like we have $7$-sided dice. We have sides $1,2,3,4,5,6$ and $6$ on dice.

Now probability of getting $6$ is $\dfrac 27$

Probability of getting any other number is $\dfrac 17$

Probability = $\dfrac 27 \cdot \dfrac 17 \cdot \dfrac 17$